# Windows 8.1 intermittent black screen now permanent, still accessible through ethernet

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card

Note, this is NOT the Black Screen of Death (KSOD), because there is no mouse cursor. In fact, the displays act like they are receiving no signal.

I used to get this intermittent black screen on startup, perhaps 1 out of 10 times or even less.

But today I've restarted 5 times and nothing will show up on either of my two monitors connected to the machine.

I started up a second computer and connected an Ethernet cable between the two and I was able to access the "dead" computer's filesystem.

(I was asked for the system password first. Does this mean that Windows 8.1 is actually up and running on the other machine, and I just can't see it on the screen? Or could I be accessing the filesystem without the OS working?)

I was afraid the hard disk might have died, but apparently that isn't the problem. If it is a video card issue, how can I fix it? Should I try to SSH with Cygwin into the machine?

The graphics card is the one that came pre-installed with this Alienware machine, so I don't know why it would cause an issue.

Update: I removed the graphics card and plugged it into another computer. It worked. I plugged it back into to the "broken" computer and it started working again. I don't know if it is fixed or if I just got lucky on the next startup. I have not restarted it since. But I will update again if the problem comes back.

Answer (score 1):

Try re-seating the video card (pulling the card out of the slot - and putting it back in) and cables from the video card and monitor(s).  It is possible there is a bad connection.  Also check to make sure the card is being cooled properly (fans spinning).  It is possible it might be overheating.  Finally, install the latest drivers.

Comment: I checked all the connections and they are as good as I can make them, and all the fans are working. The GPU fan was somewhat dusty, so I cleaned it a bit. But still nothing works. How can I install the latest drivers if I can't view the system?

Comment: You are probably going to want to test the video card in another system if possible.  Is there an integrated video connection on the motherboard?  You could use that to make sure the system is working properly, minus the video card.  You will probably have to take out the video card to use the integrated video connection.

Comment: It's an Alienware X51 r2 and the only VGA, DVI, and HDMI are on the GTX 745 (OEM) video card. I took the card out and put it into the other PC (Windows 7). After automatically installing drivers, and a restart, it works great in that machine. So it seems that the video card itself is not the problem, unfortunately.